# Difference between Framework.Triggers and Style.Triggers?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml, triggers

There are two properties of same type but exists in different classes.

- [FrameworkElement.Triggers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers.aspx)
- [Style.Triggers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx)

This confuses me a lot, and so I've few questions whose answer I'm looking for:

- Why two properties of same type exist?
- When should I use what?
- What one can do that other cannot?

Answer (score 5):

As the documentation page that you've linked to in the question says:

FrameworkElement.Triggers can only contain EventTriggers and is not usually used. You cannot define (Property based) Triggers or (data-bound value based) DataTriggers with this method.

For most practical purposes, you should be using Style.Triggers or DataTemplate.Triggers or ControlTemplate.Triggers. (Sorry for adding to the confusion).