# Storyboard exception when used in Style.Triggers as opposed to FrameworkElement.Triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom button that I am using to open/close a DevExpress FlyoutControl. The following code that has the button click event trigger defined in a FrameworkElement.Triggers collection:

```
<controls:GlyphButton Name="AvailableEcusGlyphButton">
    <controls:GlyphButton.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
             <BeginStoryboard>
                 <Storyboard>
                     <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference AvailableEcusFlyout}"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                           <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                    Value="{Binding ElementName=AvailableEcusFlyout, Path=IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}" />
                     </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
       </EventTrigger>
   </controls:GlyphButton.Triggers>
</controls:GlyphButton>
```

However, after reading recommendations that Element.Triggers are not commonly used, I decided to move the storyboard in a style applied to the button.

```
<controls:GlyphButton Name="AvailableEcusGlyphButton">
    <controls:GlyphButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:GlyphButton}">
             <Style.Triggers>
                  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                      <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard>
                              <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference AvailableEcusFlyout}"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                  <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                    Value="{Binding ElementName=AvailableEcusFlyout, Path=IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}" />
                              </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                          </Storyboard>
                      </BeginStoryboard>
                 </EventTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
        </controls.GlyphButton>
```

When the above code is loaded, the triggers collection throws the following exception at runtime.

```
{"After a 'TriggerCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified."}
```

What gives? I fail to see what is modifying the trigger collection here.

Comment: Rebuild and run and tell plz.

Comment: Element triggers not used....haven't heard that one....

Comment: I'm referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701177/difference-between-framework-triggers-and-style-triggers?rq=1) post that I found when looking for more information about when you should use either or.

Comment: @Rocket254 is your problem solved

Comment: I never had an issue with the first approach.  I am wanting to know why the storyboard fails when declared inside a style's triggers collection instead of a FrameworkElement

Answer (score 1):

Use your first approach,

and remove `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames` stuff completely and use `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` instead as below :

```
<Storyborad>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference AvailableEcusFlyout}"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                            Value="{Binding ElementName=AvailableEcusFlyout, Path=IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```